# Is it possible to enable some sort of stack trace for exceptions in profile mode?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I am running my flutter app in profile mode. But wierdly I have an error which only happens in profile and release mode but the debug console doesn't show me what the error is. Is there anyway I can see what the error is? I use vscode as my IDE.

Currently it just logs the following

```
I/flutter (29240): ══╡  ╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (29240): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `dart devtools` if ide is not showing logs properly. For visual studio code you find a search like button on run menu of flutter application to open devtools. You can also use dart observatory for detailed information.